# Complete GWT based sign-up system

Tags: gwt

have anyone come across a complete GWT app with registration/sign-up page to start with--unlike with PHP. Until now I haven't find such app that have the ability to register user, have the user a 'user page' and so on. With integration to MySQL and other db to persist user data. Does anyone know such code to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of application are you going to develop? If your project is a public website and you plan to run it on GAE, you could use Google App Engine User Service.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/

For enterprise apps this is probably not a valid option...

Comment: nope I will not be using GAE, or deploying to it. I just use Tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

A GWT app is quite useless without an appropriate backend (Java, PHP, Python, etc).
In the end GWT code is only compiled to client-side javascript code. With client-side javascript you can't access any database on the server and thus any GWT app also requires a backend in order to access a database like MySQL.

So in order to create a registration/sign-up app you have to write both backend and frontend code.
For the frontend and the UI respectively you can use GWT. For the backend you can use any server side technology. The tightest integration with GWT can be achieved with a Java backend but you can also use non-java backends like PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.
GWT will communicate either via RPC/RequestFactory (Java) or RequestBuilder (non-java backends). Fore more information refer to the GWT [docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/clientserver.html).

So I recommend following steps:

1. Decide which backend technology you are going to use. Java offers the tightest integration (RPC,RequestFactory, etc). However for small/simple apps sometimes it is easier to use non-java backends like Python or PHP because they can be setup/implemented faster/easier.
2. Implement the business logic on the server-side. In your case this includes among others "adding new users to the database", "signing up users", "retrieving user information", etc
3. Design and implement the UI with GWT. In your case this will be the user-page and the form to fill in details for signing up, etc.
4. Write the communication part between frontend and backend in GWT using RequestFactory/RPC (Java) or RequestBuilder (non-Java)

Comment: yes I know about Client-side and server side, however what I cannot find is a complete gwt app with server backend which technically have all these laid out. Instead of starting from scratch.

Comment: Well I would recommend to develop such an application from scratch because that's the best way to dive into the whole topic. Alternatively you can check out code.google.com and search for gwt-samples: i.e.: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/

Comment: I guess you're right. However to answer to your post, I am implementing with Hibernate + MySQL back-end (though I just use HSQLDB for now to keep things light.) I am researching on Spring, yet I am trying to keep things work with GWT native RPC for the server side. The reason I asked my post, is that maybe someone have done such complete app without using Spring or some sort of framework, just native GWT, Hibernate + DB (like MySQL)

Comment: There is a chapter in the GWT docs about Hibernate and GWT. Might be useful for you: http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate.html